# Connection Status with reachability

Tags: ios, connection, reachability

I'm using Reachability on my project and when I tried to get information about connection type I get this error.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus],/myProjectPath/Reachability.m:530
2012-04-03 21:25:45.619 Traffic[7862:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'currentNetworkStatus called with NULL reachabilityRef'
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I put the same code as in ReachabilityAppDelegate to get connection status.

my code:

```
// get type of user connection
NSString* statusString= @"NA";

Reachability *curReach = [[Reachability alloc] init];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL connectionRequired= [curReach connectionRequired];


switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        statusString = @"NA";
        //Minor interface detail- connectionRequired may return yes, even when the host is unreachable.  We cover that up here...
        connectionRequired= NO;
        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        statusString = @"WWAN";
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        statusString= @"WIFI";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I was checking for `if reachability.currentReachabilityStatus() == NotReachable` before doing

```
reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
reachability.startNotifier()
```

The issues is that you're asking for a status before you start the notifier, and the `_reachabilityRef` is nil.

Make sure you do the calls in their needed order. first start notifier, and then only after that check/ask for a status.

Answer (score 0):

check for:

```
//Called by Reachability whenever status changes.
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

in the app delegate. The NSParameterAssert causes the crash in my case